# Redirecting domain (not google apps) to appengine without Host records

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, google-apps, cname

I would like to redirect a domain to app engine, but my Domain provider only allows me to set information for Primary DNS and Secondary DNS. It means that there is no possibilities to set host records (cname, A, etc)

I think I do have to use a DNS Provider, but I'd like to know your opinion on what's the best way and where to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which registrar are you using? Many of the well-known ones offer DNS service on registered domains, but often in a different part of the management UI.

Comment: www.nic.cl Chilean TLD provider.

Comment: I couldn't find any mention of DNS service there, so yes, it looks like you'll need to sign up with a provider.

Answer (score 0):

I have been delighted with dns.he.net.  It is completely free for 50 domains, and gives you the control you are looking for.